# Best practice for cloning from git head into single default workspace

Tags: git, clone, workspace

I have forked two repositories that are under the same head in git.  I cloned the first fork into the STS default workspace. I then created a new folder/workspace adjacent to the default STS workspace and cloned the second forked repository into that new second workspace. The cloning succeeded but now there is a maven folder in the second workspace with a red exclamation mark.  Additionally, although both clonings succeeded, there are red exclamation marks next to the top folder in each workspace.  Can anyone explain a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Git has a basic "clone" operation but not a "fork": fork is something your provider adds on. You mention "STS", whatever that may be ("Springsource Tool Suite" perhaps). Your question should probably be directed there.

Comment: I apologize, I typed in the tag [spring-tool-suite] before asking this question so I don't know how it landed elsewhere. I will try it again.